# Rails — Can views access controller variables via attr_reader's?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know that views can access the instance variables of a controller.

Instead of using the controller's instance variables directly, can the view access these variables via attr_reader's on the controller instead?

(I know that I can use gems like decent_exposure, but I'm curious to know if there are other things I can try)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can

```
#controller 

attr_reader :foo
helper_method :foo


#view

<%= foo %>
```

Comment: Is it standard Rails's style to share data using helper_methods? (Sorry, I'm still learning Rails, and would like know what the best practices are. Accessing the controller's instance variables does not look very clean to me)